How to calculate the Draconic month on a fictional world
I am working on a world and want to be able to find out when Eclipses occur, and I found you need to know the Draconic Month, I think I have everything I need to find it, I have the inclination to the ecliptic, the longitude of the ascending node, and the argument of periapsis, along with masses of the planet and satellite, and distance between them (thus I also have orbital period).
So how can I use these to calculate the Draconic Month for my planet? What is the mathematics for finding such a thing.

Because of the complexity of your question I would like to remind you that not everything needs to be scientifically accurate. Your cycles being accurate can be an interesting detail of the story, but is absolutely not required. You could also leave it up to the reader, describing something that is possible, and having any people who want to verify the exact science behind it. That way you keep it light for the readers, allowing them to be as involved in the science as they themselves like to be. Again, wanting scientific accuracy is not a problem at all.

This is moreso a worldbuilding project than something meant for a story. And I know it is complex but I don't particularly care, I am willing to go through the work to try and make it as accurate as I can make it.

Here's the equation for the Draconic month length Tn

where:

e is the eccentricity (note that the equation only works when this is close, but not equal to zero)
a is the semi-major axis
u is the gravitational constant
J2 is a perturbation factor due to the oblateness of the planet
i is the inclination
R is the radius of the planet
w is the argument of the perigee

Good luck!

Two questions, one: What are the units for everything, that is important. Two, how do you find J? I have the polar and equatorial radiuses, so I know how oblate the planet is.

a: Meters, R: Meters, u: depends on what time units you want your answer to be in, J is unitless; J, e, w, and i are all unitless. J is just the ratio between the polar and equatorial diameter.

Thanks, much appreciated! Now what about question 2?

Just the ratio between the radii.

+1 not only for a specifically complete answer but in celebration, admiration, and downright awe of the lifetimes certainly spent consuming caffeine and bicarbonates just to come up with that equation. Praise Glarnak!

Thanks, but I really just looked it up.

The draconic month is equal to a sidereal month (= orbital period of the satellite) minus the precession of the nodes during that sidereal month. If you know the period of the nodal precession of the satellite $T_\text{nodal}$ and the sidereal month $T_\text{sidereal}$ then the draconic month $T_\text{draconic}$ is about
$$T_\text{draconic} \approx T_\text{sidereal} \left( 1 - \frac{T_\text{sidereal}}{T_\text{nodal}} \right)$$
(The sign is minus if we assume that both the planet and the satellite revolve in the same direction, which is the normal situation.)
I do not know of any easy (or at least not fiendishly difficult) method to calculate or even estimate the nodal precession of the satellite, because it depends on the actual shapes of the planet, of the satellite, and of the star around which the planet-satellite system revolves. If the planet, the satellite and the star were all perfectly spherical there would be no precession of the nodes.
In practice, just make it up; any value measured in thousands of days would be perfectly believable; moreover, nobody can say that the value you have chose is incorrect because see preceding paragraph. For reference, the period of the nodal precession of our own Moon is currently about 6,793 days.
Don't get too carried away with calculating everything with the utmost precision. Consider that our own Moon is close at hand, astronomers have been observing it for more than four thousand years, and yet the theory of the motions of the Moon remains an extremely complicated subject.

I know how oblate the planet is, I found what the polar and equatorial radii should be. So what would I do then to find nodal precession? And it should be easy to find it for the moon as well.

@DanceroftheStars: The major contributor to the precession of the nodes of the satellite is the torque exerted by the star on the planet–satellite system as a whole. This depends on the shape of the star; the effect of the shape of the planet is non-negligible, but much smaller. Sorry, I don't have a university degree in classical mechanics, and here it would be really needed.

Ah, bummer, but understandable. You think maybe I should ask in the Astronomy stack exchange?

@DanceroftheStars: You could try; it won't do any harm I can think of. But as far as I know the precession of the nodes of our very own Moon is a measured value, not computed from first principles. And then anyway you would need to take into account the perturbations due to other Big Things in the system, such as Jupiter in our real-world system. In practice, our best current models can only predict solar eclipses accurately up to about 1,000 years in the future, and with lower and lower accuracy up to 3,000 years in the future.

@DanceroftheStars: Remember that fundamentally almost any gravitationally bound system consisting of more than two bodies is chaotic on the long term. There are no closed-form formulas, and there cannot be. The nice Wikipedia article on lunar months has a great table giving the current best estimations of the various cycles; note the presence of a time-dependent uncertainty factor in all the cycles.
